# Hibernate Composite key Annotation and Database Change

Tags: hibernate

Hi I have to create a composite primary key in my Hibernate Entity, and i am using annotation for it. Is it necessary to add a constraint for the same composite key in database, if we create a composite key in Hibernate Side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** it is not mandatory but Its always good practice to have the constraints at database level as well,so as to avoid accidental changes  due to direct operations on database (manually or by jobs ect) which do not use hibernate layer.

Comment: Thanks Amit for Immediate Answer.